# Probability of choosing exactly three men or three women

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to do this task

Suppose that in a village with 80 inhabitants, we randomly select people to fill the positions in the local government. We also know that there are 40 men and 40 women. What is the probability that in one selection, we will choose a triplet in which not all people are of the same gender?

Let's denote the probability of a triplet where not all people are of the same gender as $P$.

At first I thought that the answer would be
$$
P = 1- 2 \frac{{40\choose 3}}{{80\choose 3}}\approx 0.758
$$
Since we have the probability of choosing either three women $\frac{{40\choose 3}}{{80\choose 3}}$ or three men $\frac{{40\choose 3}}{{80\choose 3}}$.
But when I wrote a code for this I've got the answer
$$
P \approx 0.750
$$

Is there a mistake in my calculation?

Comment: Why would $\frac{{40\choose 2}}{{80\choose 2}}$ be the probability of chosing three women?

Comment: That was a mistake, I've made an edit.

Comment: First, you seem to have a typo... you wrote "choose 2" rather than "choose 3" in your binomial coefficients.  Second, 0.75 is notably the probability *with replacement* but these selections are presumably *without replacement*.  Check your code that you can not select the same person more than once within a selection.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that was exactly it. I didn't consider the replacement part in the code.

Comment: It is worth noting that as the size of the population gets bigger and bigger, this will get closer to the result had there been replacement.  With 800 people the probability would be $\approx 0.75094$ and with 8000 people it would be $\approx 0.750094$ and so on... so if dealing with "*large*" populations we will often simplify and approximate the problem by using replacement... but otherwise with smaller problems like this it can not be overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collating comments to remove from answer queue:

Your calculation is correct.  There is nothing more to comment on there.

Your code came up with the result corresponding to if our selection of people was done with replacement and so presumably has an error in the sampling process allowing you to "select the same person" more than once within a sample.

Comment: Exactly right, when I removed the error the probabilities match to the precision I gave in the question